# getting partial xml with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml looks like this

```
    <page id="1">
        <fields>
            <field typeid="4" id="1" order="1" qnumber="1">
                <property>
                    <label>question1</label>
                    <options>
                        <option id="18" order="2">option 1</option>
                        <option id="19" order="3">option 2</option>
                        <option id="20" order="4">option 3</option>
                    </options>
                    <maxOptions></maxOptions>
                    <isrequired>false</isrequired>
                </property>
            </field>
            <field typeid="3" id="5" order="5" qnumber="2">
                <property>
                    <label>question 5</label>
                    <options>
                        <option id="21" order="6">option 1</option>
                        <option id="22" order="7">option 2</option>
                        <option id="23" order="8">option 3</option>
                    </options>
                    <maxOptions></maxOptions>
                    <isrequired>false</isrequired>
                </property>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </page>
```

I parsed the above xml with

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(a);
```

with the input value, I want to to be able to display only the xml that the user selected (for saving purpose)

so I used:

```
$(xmlDoc).find('field').each(function ()
{        

    $("#output").val($(this).val());

});
```

but it wouldn't display anything, I tried .text() and won't work as well, can anyone point me to a right direction? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to save time, I wrote a little function that'll take an xml node and output it to the string. I hope this will be beneficial to someone in the future who needs it:

```
function XMLtoString(xmlNode)
{
    var rstr = "";
    var node = $(xmlNode).get(0);

    rstr = "<" + node.nodeName;

    if (node.attributes.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++)
        {
            rstr += " " + node.attributes[i].name + "=\"" + node.attributes[i].value + "\"";
        }
    }

    rstr += ">";

    if ($(node).children().length > 0)
    {
        $(node).children().each(function ()
        {
            rstr += XMLtoString($(this));
        });
    }
    else //asume reached the end childnode, then only write the value (not attribute)
    {
        rstr += $(node).text();
    }

    return rstr += "</" + node.nodeName + ">";
}
```

Happy coding!!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you were in the html body, you could normally use `$(this).html()` (where you tried using `$(this).val()`, but this is not available in xml documents.

From http://api.jquery.com/html/ :

> This method is not available on XML documents.

So, the only option I know of is to rebuild the xml data by visiting all the children. If you already know the structure, that makes it easier. Something like this:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlText);
var output="";    
    $(xmlDoc).find( "field" ).each(function() {
        $(this).find( "property" ).each(function() {
            output+= '<property>';
            $(this).find( "label" ).each(function() {    
                output+= '<label>';
                output+= $(this).text();
                output+= '</label>\n';
            });
            //FILL IN options, maxOptions and isRequired here ..
            output+= '</property>\n';
        });
    });
alert(output);
```

I have only done part of it. You'd have to complete the options, maxOptions and isRequired fields yourself. See `attr()` method for accessing attributes: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

You can see my example in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/M6MsY/1/

HTH

Comment: thanks HTH for your comments. I was thinking my last resort would be going that route, but it's just going to take some work. Suppose is there any way to get the name of each node? I was thinking to use a recursive method that'll just traverse through each child, each attribute and write it out.

do you know how to get the name of the node? for example if I use $(this).children().each(function{ find node name and attribute and write out xml here });

I suppose there's no $(this).xmlNodeName()?

Comment: found something on other page, use this.nodeName (without the dollar sign) would give the node name, and I can loop through each attribute with this

$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
     var name = attrib.name;
     var value = attrib.value;
     //...
  });
});

suppose I should come up with a function where the user just pass in the xml, and this function will spit out the strings, (to be continued...)